# WMI library/firmware in Alljoyn thin

Tags: alljoyn

As I understand WSL stands for **WMI SPI Layer** - After going through the code, WSL seems to be a wrapper layer where it just marshals/unmarshals the command/data/events over an SPI interface and *actual* processing is done in the firmware.

Does anyone have references to this firmware/driver ? What does **WMI** stand for ? Does WMI/WSL runs on QC4004 chips only ?

Comment: I'll appreciate if someone who has down-voted it can also point out why it was done so ? Alljoyn is a fairly new topic and having certain ambiguity or lack of clarity is possible as people are still exploring it -  Down-voting it without citing the reason is not helpful at all.

Comment: the release notes for 14.06 mention running it on a Due: https://git.allseenalliance.org/cgit/core/ajtcl.git/tree/ReleaseNotes.txt?h=v14.06 I don't remember what WMI stands for